# Understanding dojo hitch

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am struggling to understand hitch function of the dojo toolkit. I am looking at this example at https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/lang.html, which is the following:

```
require(["dojo/_base/lang"], function(lang){
var myObj = {
    foo: "bar",
    method: function(someArg){
      console.log(this.foo);
    }
  };

  var func = lang.hitch(myObj, "method");

  func();
});
```

Is it not possible to utilize that function by myObj.method(arg) instead? Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it not possible to utilize that function by `myObj.method(arg)` instead?

Yes, it is in that particular case, but it's quite common to need to pass a function reference to other code, and function references don't (by default) carry any particular `this` baked into them; `this` gets set by how you call the function.

So for instance, if you use `myObj.method` as an event handler, when it gets called, `this` during the call won't refer to the object `myObj` refers to.

`hitch` fixes that by creating a new function that, when called, will call your method with `this` set correctly.

It's been dated for some time, ES5 (in 2009) introduced `Function#bind`, which does the same thing. But the Dojo Toolkit was initially created back in 2005, so it included utilities like this. Here's that same code using `Function#bind` instead:

```
require(["dojo/_base/lang"], function(lang){
  var myObj = {
    foo: "bar",
    method: function(someArg){
      console.log(this.foo);
    }
  };

  var func = myObj.method.bind(myObj);

  func();
});
```

Here's a live example demonstrating how it can matter in an event handler:

```js
var obj = {
  foo: "bar",
  method: function() {
    console.log("this.foo = " + this.foo);
  }
};
document.getElementById("unbound").addEventListener("click", obj.method, false);
document.getElementById("bound").addEventListener("click", obj.method.bind(obj), false);
```

```html
<input type="button" id="unbound" value="Unbound">
<input type="button" id="bound" value="Bound">
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I am starting to understand. I am new to JavaScript programming. Is the need for utilities like this due to the asynchronous nature of JavaScript?

Comment: @Naci: No. :-) In fact, JavaScript doesn't *have* an asynchronous nature. JavaScript, the language, is almost entirely synchronous. The first (and so far only) asynchronous aspect of it was added in ES2015 (the guarantee that callback to `then` or `catch` on a promise will always be called asynchronously). *(cont'd)*

Comment: *(continuing)* But JS is commonly used in *environments* dominated by asynchronous behavior: Browsers and NodeJS. But that's not the reason for utilities like this, it's just a parallel thing. For instance: The callback you give `Array#sort` is synchronous, but if you wanted to call an object method for that, you'd need `bind`, for the same reason you need it with an event handler (which is asynchronous).

Comment: Side note: Enjoy your journey into JS! It's a *fantastic* language. Modern C# gives it a run for its money, but I absolutely love JS.

Comment: Thank you. It is really different for me. I did Java and Matlab most recently, and the logic appears to be much different. I think this article makes it a bit clearer also: http://davidshariff.com/blog/javascript-this-keyword/. This has to do what context the object is in as far as I understand, correct?

Comment: @Naci: I don't like using "context" in relation to `this`, but unfortunately a number of people do it. I don't like it because there's something called an "execution context" which is a completely different, but slightly related, thing. `this` is just...`this`. Three of my (slightly dated) articles: [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html), [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html), and [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)